# Facebook graph API: Upload photo to page album

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem uploading photos to an album on a facebook page. Uploading a photo to the page is no problem but with the album it doesn't work.

Here's the code (copied from an example):

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once 'vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app_id','app-secret');
$scope = array('publish_actions');

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'url' );

try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
    /* make the API call */
    $request = new FacebookRequest(
        $session,
        'POST',
        '/page-id/albums?name=albumname/photos',
        array (
            'url' => 'url',
        )
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    /* handle the result */
} else {
    // show login url
    echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}
```

When i try this i get the message:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message '(#100) Invalid ID for album owner' in...

Does anyone know whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/page-id/albums?name=albumname` is for *creating* a new album with that name.

To publish a photo to an existing album, you have to post to `/{album-id}/photos`.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/album/photos#publish for more details.

Comment: Ok thanks, thats the right edge. Works fine in graph explorer but not as script. Probably wrong token. Damn, i hate those tokens :D